# C++ でイベントリスナーとは何を指す？

Tags: c++

C++でイベントリスナーと言うとなにでしょうか？

ドキュメントをよんでいると以下の文章がでてきまして、リスナークラスというものがあるのでしょうか？
検索してもはっきりとわからず、もしかしてキーワードが異なるのか？と思っているのですが。何かお心当たりありましたら教えていだだけますと助かります。

> イベントを受信する場合は、リスナークラスを登録して下さい

Comment: 可能であれば参照したドキュメントの出典 (URL 等) を明記してみてください。

Comment: C++言語ではなくOSのAPIやSDK/ライブラリ/フレームワークの関係かもしれません。だから @cubick さんのコメントのように、何を対象としたドキュメントであるかの(誰でも確認できる)正確な情報が必要です。ドキュメントの作者が他から類似した内容の言葉を引っ張ってきて記述しているだけかもしれませんし。[イベントの追加 (ATL チュートリアル、パート 5)](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/atl/adding-an-event-atl-tutorial-part-5?view=msvc-170), [ネイティブ C++ でのイベント処理](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/cpp/event-handling-in-native-cpp?view=msvc-170), [C++でイベントリスナ（その1）](http://farog.blog34.fc2.com/blog-entry-14.html), [C++でjava風リスナを実装する](https://setuna-kanata.hatenadiary.org/entry/20081207/1228668906)

Comment: ありがとうございます。引き続き探したところ、イベント用クラスと登録用の関数を発見しまして、どうやらリスナークラスというのはSDK独自のクラスのことだったようです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ の言語仕様としての用語にイベントリスナーというものはありません。

一般的にはイベントに対してアクションを起こすオブジェクトのことですが、具体的にどのような性質があるのかはその SDK がどういうものか次第です。 SDK のドキュメントに書かれているはずなのでそれを読んでください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。やはりないのですね。他の情報も探してみます。